# how to apply button background color dynamically using color resources in color.xml file

Tags: android, button, background-color

I am trying to apply  background color  to button dynamically using color id in color resource file(color.xml).

> `btn.setBackgroundColor(R.color.green);`

i also tried this

```
btn.setBackgroundColor(Resources.getSystem().getColor(R.color.green));
```

but its not working.

if i apply

```
btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.Green);
```

Its working.

But i need to apply color resource from color.xml file. Please let me know how i can do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use this:

```
btn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Green));
```

and second way:

```
Resources resources = YourActivity.this.getResources();  
Drawable drawable = resources.getDrawable(R.color.Green);
btn.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

your color.xml look like:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
    <resources>  
        <drawable name="red">#f00</drawable>  
        <drawable name="green">#0f0</drawable>  
        <drawable name="gray">#ccc</drawable>  
    </resources>
```

**EDIT
Now that getColor() is deprecated :

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Under values create xml called colors, add your custom colors to that one.
Now you can write R.color."name"
(aka. rename color to colors)