# change color of button when list item is selected

Tags: android, listview, button, colors, android-actionbar

i'm working on a listview in an activity and i want when ever i longpressed any listitem the Button on the action bar changes its color like as get highlihted  as suppose  " **i select
list item the button on the action bar changes from white to gray"** .

```
   listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // changes the color button ;
            return false;
        }
    });
```

or is there any other way that i can do this.

I dont have enough reputation to post a pictures Firstly it looks like [Before selecting any item](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7p072bzqjn8fe9j/Screenshot_2015-02-02-11-48-36.png?dl=0)  and its looks like this[When item is long pressed or selected](https://www.dropbox.com/s/glmqrb4l26vbj6c/Screenshot_2015-02-02-11-31-11.png?dl=0)  hope you understand my probleum , 
Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26903094/2389078

Comment: dude is there any way to do it from styles or xml ?

Comment: people here have lots of knowledge and find this question unprofessional !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: as misunderstood original question:

```
int mPosition = -1;   

lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int pos, long id) {

        if(mPosition!=-1) {
            //reset color of previously pressed item to white
            lv.getChildAt(mPosition).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        //set current item to fray.
        lv.getChildAt(pos).setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        //put value of currently selected item to mPosition.
        mPosition = pos;

        return true;
    }
});
```

Old answer below:

Add this into your method.

```
Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
if(this condition){
    button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
}else{
    //whatever.. 
}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10295483/3956566) covers the same principle, but in more detail using the resources.

Comment: bro it is needed to be changed dynamically, like we do in tab bar that if "if item is selected "

Comment: i'm using a listview . and whenever any list item is long pressed the button on the **action bar** changes its color

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/glmqrb4l26vbj6c/Screenshot_2015-02-02-11-31-11.png?dl=0     you can lookupon this image in this item is selected and things on action bar changes

Comment: Half of the part is done "that is changing the color of listitem " but i also want actionbar to change its color and buttons"  whenanyof item is selected as shown in above picture as happening in **gmail app**

Answer (score 0):

you can give color to list item when selected with

`android:listSelector="@color/AnyColor"` in .xml file .. see coding

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/nameOfYourListview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="AnyYouWant"
   <!--code for color the selected item --> android:listSelector="ColorHereWhichYouWant" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18549271/highlight-custom-listview-item-when-long-click) .. may this can help you